# I can't view my wordpress blog posts on MAMP

Tags: wordpress, mamp

I started a Wordpress blog last week, currently it is sitting in htdocs within MAMP. I was getting on with it well last week, viewing the site through localhost, and viewing my posts.

Coming back to it this morning I can view my dashboard at http://localhost:8888/blog/wp-admin/ I can also see my blog at the list of posts at http://localhost:8888/blog/ but when I click on a blog it says

"Not Found

The requested URL localhost:8888/blog/2015/09/10/hello-world/ was not found on this server."

(the url being localhost:8888/blog/2015/09/10/hello-world/)

What would of caused this? I don't think I've changed anything other then switching themes and a little custom css.

Comment: Try regenerating your permalinks (just go to Settings .. Permalinks and save).  Something weird might be cached.

Comment: check URL rewrite mode

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @hobo! a nice and simple fix!

I just needed to regenerating the permalinks (just go to Settings .. Permalinks and save).

thanks!